# Routing with Web Forms - Could not load System.Web.Routing

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms

I am using:

- ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 with Web Forms
- Routing thru Global.asax (System.Web.Routing and RegisterRoutes)
- IIS 7

Everything is working fine in my local machine, but it gives the following error in my hosting environment:

**Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I did everything inside my web.config file mentioned in the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr...8VS.90%29.aspx

But I am still getting the above error.

What else am I supposed to do fix the error?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible that some settings in `web.config` are missing which are necessary when you host your application in IIS. Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx), especially Figure 2 which describes the configuration entries for IIS 7.

I remember that in ASP.NET 4 setting

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

was enough and adding the modules and handlers in Figure 2 of this article wasn't required. But in ASP.NET 3.5 it might be necessary.

Comment: Adding the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests property to modules node and putting the Routing dll into the Bin directory did the trick. Thanks Slauma!